# Does Android sync require Facebook?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star, android, facebook

So I still haven't linked Facebook to TDS, partially because I don't want to give any more information than I have to, among other things.

Every now and then, though, when TDS crashes and I restart it, I'm presented with the usual "local or online" save selection screen. So far I've only ever done local, either because the age of the save is exactly the same, or it's half a day old online.

Does anybody have experience with using Sync without connecting to Facebook on Android? I haven't tried syncing it to other devices yet, so I'm a bit concerned that if I don't do so, and I have to reinstall the game, that the online save actually won't work!

(And yes, I know the obvious answer would be to use Facebook sync, but each platform is different, and Android may be doing something else.)